# Making predictions based on the data of 1 'sample'

Tags: sampling, predictive-models, prediction, bootstrap, small-sample

Let's assume that we have a dataset $D$ consisting of $n$ samples/instances $x_i$ and a particular value of $Y$. The objective is to predict the quantity $Y$ for some arbitrary dataset. We know that the training set in principal consists of just 1 sample but also that the $Y$ value can be calculated by using the information of the samples $x_i$ in $D$.

In order to construct a larger trainingset, my idea is to take random subsamples $D^j$ in $D$ and calculate the respective $Y^j$. My question is whether it is a more valid approach to take random subsamples of fixed size (for example $n$) with replacement (a.k.a. bootstrapping, infinite size of the trainingset is possible in this case) or that I can better take random samples of random size $m<n$ (in which case the trainingset could theoretically consist of $\sum_{i=1}^n$${n}\choose{i}$ instances). Furthermore, is this a valid and general approach to construct a larger trainingset where we use the information 'in' the sample(s)?

Comment: This is a form of bootstrapping, and it's quite popular. Also, "leave one out" cross validation uses a similar approach. Whether the subsample sample is fixed or changing is not important as long as you account for size. The only thing is that your data set does not become larger.

Comment: Can you say more about the $Y^j$ as you call it? Is the $Y$ just the sum of respective $Y^j$s and so you are trying to predict an aggregate?

Comment: In fact $Y=\Sigma_{i=1}^n Y_i$ where $Y_i$ is some unknown way dependent of $x_i$. Now take some random subset $\sigma_j \in $ {1,...,n} and let $Y^j = \Sigma_{\sigma_j} Y_i$. It is true indeed that we're directly trying to make predictions of some aggegrate value $Y'$ which belongs to some 'arbitrary' set of samples $D'$ by making use of our newly constructed trainingsset {$X^j, Y^j$} where $X^j$ is a feature vector created on basis of the information in some $D^j$.

Comment: To give an explanation in a less abstract setting: We have a dataset consisting of different objects and the costs being made on these objects; hence we also know the total costs being made. For some future dataset with new objects, we would specifically like to predict the total cost belonging to these objects. I can also decide to make predictions on the individual costs of the new objects but in this sense it is unclear to me how to create a prediction interval for the total costs (and it is irrelevant to me what the costs per object shall be, I'm just interested in the total).